# How to bypass batch error step in Jenkins project

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins project in which i run a sonarqube analysis in a windows OS.

In jenkins , I created a batch step more or less like this:

```
mycommand test --machine --coverage > tests.output
sonar-scanner
```

*mycommand* is a 3rd party plugin which i can't modify , and, based on the content of the project , this step can fail and I want the jenkins queue to go on with the other command .

Now if mycommand return an error jenkins stop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what operating system  ?

Comment: @rasjani edited with the correct OS

Comment: Why is this tagged _bash_, but in your text you refer to _batch_??? What language are you using here, bash or Windows batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic here is in the return code from your command. Without knowing what it is and what it does, the important thing is that if any command returns non-zero exit code Jenkins will see the command as failed. To prevent any errors from being registered by Jenkins add `exit 0` to the command.

For example

```
bat """
mycommand test --machine --coverage > tests.output || exit /b 0
"""
bat """
sonar-scanner
"""
```

Should work for this.

Alternatively you can also chain the commands together with `&` so Jenkins doesn't check the exit codes before everything is completed, but then the second command will also **always** show as passed regardless of its real status. Also it can become difficult to read with lengthy command chains.

```
bat """
mycommand test --machine --coverage > tests.output & sonar-scanner & exit /b 0
"""
```

Comment: mycommand test --machine --coverage   1>tests.output  || exit /b 0 
No tests were found.
Finished: SUCCESS

did not launch the 2nd command

Comment: You will need to add a separate step for the second command because of the ``exit`` command (see the example). You can also chain both commands with ``&`` if the second command also should never fail, but that can become difficult to read quite fast.

Comment: tried with 2 build steps and works as I wanted